# What is the issue with this pyschools exercise?

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

In the Pyschool recursion exercise, there was this question to print the numbers inbetween two give arguments (inclusive of those).. I am sooo weak at recursion, but after certain tries, I made that happen.. But it still throws the error though the Expected result and the Returned result are exactly same..

```
def numbersInbetween(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return "Invalid"
    if a == b:
        return a
    else:

        return str(a)+ "," + str(numbersInbetween(a+1, b))
```

the output image file:

[image]

I even tried, to string format the output in the second `if` statement, but that only throws an error like "Check for infinite loop in your code".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You return `a` when `a == b`, not `str(a)`. The tester expects a string, you gave it an integer instead.

You probably *also* want to test for `b` being *smaller* than `a`, otherwise you can end up recursing endlessly (well, until you hit the recursion limit):

```
if b < a:
    return "Invalid"
```

If `b = 0`, the function will still work *provided `a` is smaller or equal to `b`*. `numbersInbetween(5, 0)` returns `"Invalid"` not because `b` is `0`, but because `b` is smaller than `a`; you'll never reach `a == b` when you increment `a` in such cases.

Making sure that your function always returns a string actually simplifies your code a little:

```
def numbersInbetween(a, b):
    if b < a:
        return "Invalid"
    if a == b:
        return str(a)
    else:
        return str(a) + "," + numbersInbetween(a + 1, b)
```

Comment: Yes, but as I already mentioned, when I format the output as string, it throws an error as **Error: timeout. The server may be busy or check the code for possible endless loop.**  Also, if i use your code, I probably get another error as int and string cannot be concatenated.. Since in the else statement, the function output is not formatted as a string..

Comment: @user3494845: no, the function *always returns a string*. Either `"Invalid"`, or `str(a)` or `str(a)` plus a comma plus a recursive call.

Comment: here is the output of the code exactly you have given..http://i.imgur.com/vtSl77e.png

Comment: @user3494845: Your function does not, however, test for `b` being *smaller* than `a`. It doesn't matter if `b` is 0, if `a` is -1 that'll work.

Comment: I think a bit of miscommunication here... see this page..  http://www.pyschools.com/quiz/view_question/s11-q10 , it asks to display the numbers separated by commas using recursive function.. but when I did it, it never resolves... everything is formatted perfectly... And the "Invalid" return for b == 0 is the question requirement..

Comment: @vinoth: no, `b == 0` is **not** a requirement. `0` is lower than `5` there, which is why it is invalid.

Comment: @MartijnPieters wow, that's clear.. I changed the condition to b < a, But still the main problem resides.. for that a == b test.. Do you think this maybe an issue with the site?

Comment: Totally Strange!!! I fired up mozilla, and it worked there...!!..Recursion seriously sucks, thanks for your help..  {OUT OF SCOPE}  if possible, do you happen to have any sorts of tutorial links to get clear understanding recursion? All I could find was the syntax docs..

Comment: Nope, sorry; recursion has been a done deal for me for decades, so I have no current tutorials for you.

Answer (score 0):

Change line **if** b == 0 into **if** b < 0 **or** b==0

```
    def numbersInbetween(a, b):
        if b < a or b == 0:
            return "Invalid"
        if a == b:
            return str(a)  
        else:
            return str(a) + ',' + numbersInbetween(a+1, b)
```